# How to get the AST from YACC?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, yacc, bison

I know how to make YACC generate an AST, but how do you actaully get it? I mean, how do you actaully get the value of the root node from YACC?

Comment: None of you seem to understand my question. **Where do I actually get the semantic value of the root nonterminal?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yacc only gives you back one node at a time, and it's *always* something that you just gave yacc at some earlier time, i.e., whatever you wanted to return from a reduced production or whatever you wanted to return from a terminal symbol. (Sorry, you said you knew that, but some people reading this might not.)

So, take whatever you woud have returned from the root or top rule, and save it (in your attached C reduction code) any way you like.

Comment: How on earth do I take what the top rule returned? That's what my whole question is about!

Comment: Easy, like this: `toprule: expression_list { some_global = whatever_you_were_going_to_return };`  In other words, instead of `{ $$ = e; }` you just write `{ globalsym = e; }` instead.

Comment: Uhm that's not thread-safe. Could you come up with a thread-safe solution? PS: I use a push pure parser in bison.

Answer (score 2):

What Yacc gives you is a parse tree, which is different than an AST. You'd need to construct your AST by yourselves while going through each node of the parse tree (through yacc).

Comment: What does that mean, and how is it relavent to my question?

Comment: An AST is fundamentally different than a parse tree. Parse tree still contains syntactic information in the tree where as an AST does not have them. Yacc does not give you an AST, it only gives you a parse tree. You can read about their difference from Wikipedia.
Therefore the answer to your q is, you cannot get it from yacc. You have to define your own your AST nodes and construct it from the parse tree.

Comment: Explain to me how yacc does _not_ generate an AST here: http://pastebin.com/SBfbMXNB

Comment: Oh this is a miscommunication here clearly, my bad.. So looks like the question is really about interfacing with yacc and lex from C++.
For that case, I don't have the answer on top of my head, sorry =(.
The best I can do is, to show you some example from here (if you are using bison) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison. And also read the official manual such as: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#C_002b_002b-Bison-Interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

in the yacc file (your_grammar.y):

```
%parse-param {AstNode **pproot}
%parse-param {char **errmsg}
```

in the calling program (your_program.c):

```
res = yyparse(&pAst, &errmsg);
```

AST nodes are allocated and linked as a tree inside yyparse() (you make the logic) and the address of root node is passed back in the pAst pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as elegant as having the parser return an AST directly, but the best way that I've come up with to do this is to have a global data structure (e.g. a vector or linked list), with threadsafe insertion methods if thread safety is needed, and have the top-level yacc rule add its result (a.k.a. `$$`) to that data structure. Then you can access this result in other functions. Of course, if you're only going to output a single AST, it's probably only necessary to have a single global pointer to that AST, rather than a data structure full of them.