# Config files + yacc; how to actually get the data

Tags: parsing, config, yacc

I've written a simple config file parser in yacc, which processes files like this:

```
asdf=50
foobar=42
```

I.e. word=number.

My question is, how do I integrate this into my program? I would ultimately like to have the processed values stored in some internal data structure that I can access later as I please. Every yacc example I have seen simply printf()s the value out to stdout, but that seems kind of useless in an actual program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace those printf's by code that inserts the data into a data structure of your own. Something like this:

```
rule: TOKEN1 TOKEN2 TOKEN3 
      {
          add_data(your_data, $1, $2, $3);
      };
```

where `add_data` is a function that adds the data contained in `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` to a custom data structure contained in the variable `your_data`.

I'm afraid `your_data` has to be global. I dug in some old yacc projects I have and in other stackoverflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641199/how-to-get-the-ast-from-yacc) and I haven't found another way of doing it. If someone knows of a better way, please comment.

If you post your code I can try to help you with specifics.